# Dimming screen around dialog

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface

A popular feature in many applications - dimming a screen around a modal dialog.
I need to implement this feature on Windows Mobile, C++.
The main wnd is fullscreen, but contains many subwindows. How can everything be dimmed around specific rectangle(bounding required modal window) ?

Comment: I thought all modal dialogs on Windows Mobile were supposed to be fullscreen also? Are you sure that you're not talking about Windows CE here?

Answer (score 1):

On Win32, you can achieve this by placing a semi-transparent full-screen black Window on top of the desktop. Look for examples of rendering semi-transparent splash screens to find an example. Typically GDI+ is used.

Postscript: I just saw the "Mobile" word in your question - not sure how this will apply in that environment.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the BitBlt api (http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/aa930997.aspx) with PaintRect so you can paint the hole screen with a copy of current desktop as a transparent.

Sorry I haven't been more detailed, cause I don't remember how to do it.

--edit:
More links to help you out, both provide the answers to your need:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=534771
http://www.developer.com/ws/pc/article.php/2190121